# Redux action no longer works when defining mapDispatchToProps As A Function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, redux-actions

In a container, I've been using the "object shorthand" form of `mapDispatchToProps` to make available a single redux action (initialized as `createRoutine` from `redux-actions`) in an event handler:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = {
  validateAddress,
}
```

In the handler, the action appears in this form:

```
function () { return dispatch(actionCreator.apply(this, arguments));}
```

All good. But when instead I define `mapDispatchToProps` as a function, so that I can add other actions that need access to `dispatch`, like so...

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
      validateAddress: () => dispatch(validateAddress()),
      newAction1: .......,
      newAction2: .......,
  }
}
```

...my original action, `validateAddress`, ceases to work and appears now in this form instead:

```
function validateAddress() {
  return dispatch(Object(_core_address_module__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_9__["validateAddress"])());
}
```

I'm not sure why this is happening or how to restore the functionality of my original action. Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your action creators such as `validateAddress` should return an object or a function that receives dispatch and getState functions for thunk actions.

Here is a working example:

```js
const { Provider } = ReactRedux;
const { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } = Redux;

const initialState = {
  validateAddress: 0,
};
//action types
const VALIDATE_ADDRESS = 'VALIDATE_ADDRESS';
//action creators
function validateAddress() {
  return { type: VALIDATE_ADDRESS };
}
const reducer = (state, { type }) => {
  if (type === VALIDATE_ADDRESS) {
    return {
      ...state,
      validateAddress: state.validateAddress + 1,
    };
  }
  return state;
};
//selectors
const selectValidateAddress = (state) =>
  state.validateAddress;
//creating store with redux dev tools
const composeEnhancers =
  window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;
const store = createStore(
  reducer,
  initialState,
  composeEnhancers(
    applyMiddleware(() => (next) => (action) =>
      next(action)
    )
  )
);
const App = ({ validateAddress, actionCalled }) => {
  return (
    <button onClick={validateAddress}>
      call action, called {actionCalled} times
    </button>
  );
};
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    validateAddress: () => dispatch(validateAddress()),
  };
};
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  actionCalled: selectValidateAddress(state),
});
const AppContainer = ReactRedux.connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(App);
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <AppContainer />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/redux/4.0.5/redux.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-redux/7.2.0/react-redux.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```